# SQL Query Count same position

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(points) AS pos FROM xxx WHERE `points` >= '".$result->points."'
```

So it selects the position of an entry. The problem appears when 2 entries have the same points. Let's say there are 4 entries. It counts 1, 2, 4, 4, 5 (but I want 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 which is more senseful I think). Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Why would 1,2,3,3,5 make more sense than 1,2,4,4,5 since you're counting points? Why subtract a point?

Comment: There's two tied for the same place. How would you break ties? Insertion order?

Comment: please read [**my post**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) on how to ask a good question... you are missing key details here, and currently I don't understand what the reason is for your expected result and or why it even matters.

Comment: it's a highscore, and i count the points so that i get a highscore list. and every highscore has 1,2,3,3,5 instead of 1,2,4,4,5

Answer (score 1):

Your query;

```
"SELECT COUNT(points) AS pos FROM xxx WHERE `points` >= '".$result->points."'"
```

will count how many users have at least as many points, which always counts the user as last place among those with the same points.

If you instead count how many users have *more* points and add one, you'll count the user as the first place among the same points;

```
"SELECT 1 + COUNT(points) AS pos FROM xxx WHERE `points` > '".$result->points."'"
```

Comment: I still get the same behavior 1, 2, 4, 4, 5 :/

Comment: @Phil Odd, could you add some sample data that shows the behavior? [This SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1d87/3) shows the difference between the approaches.